# RecyclerView notifyItemMoved() not updating position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Why notifyItemMoved not re-binding( i mean `onBindViewHolder` not calls) my recyclerView's adapter?  After moving item on top or bottom i'm getting old position on click

How can i get current position of my itemView by click on it?

my move methods of recycler

```
    fun moveUp(position: Int){
    if(position>0){
        itemList.swap(position, position-1)
        notifyItemMoved(position, position-1)
    }
}
fun moveDown(position: Int){
    if(itemList.lastIndex>position){
        itemList.swap(position, position + 1)
        notifyItemMoved(position, position + 1 )

    }
}
```

my bind method

```
    override fun View.bind(item: Document, position: Int) {
    document_name.text = getFileName(item.file)
    this.setOnClickListener{
        onItemClick(this, position)

    }
```

Comment: did you try with notifyDatasetChange or notifyItemChange? this is not the correct solution but you will understand if the problem is around the position or something else..

Comment: @GiulioPettenuzzo notifyDatasetChange works perfectly, but i loose my animations in this case

Comment: so what if you call notifyDatasetChange once the animation is completed?

Comment: what is this weird "bind" method? post your adapters `onBindViewHolder`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`notifyItemMoved()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyitemmoved) is supposed to be called when items have *moved* but not *changed* :

> This is a structural change event. Representations of other existing
>   items in the data set are still considered up to date and **will not be
>   rebound, though their positions may be altered**.

This means that the position given to `onBindViewHolder()` is subject to change. 
You can use [`ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()) to get the current position.

Comment: if i use it in my  `bind` i'll get the same problem, it means, that i this method useless for me, so what's the right way to bind?

Comment: The click listener should have a reference to the `ViewHolder`, to be able to call `getAdapterPosition()` at click time

Answer (score 0):

try to use `notifyItemChanged(position, payload)`  after notifyItemMoved.
it doesn't stop draging !

or

use `holder.adapterPosition` !

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the position of viewholder you have to notify the adapter of which items are changed for that you can use `notifyItemRangeChanged(startPosition,itemCount)` method available in your adapter.

```
      override fun onMove(
                p0: RecyclerView,
                p1: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                p2: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                val sourcePosition = p1.adapterPosition
                val targetPosition = p2.adapterPosition
                Collections.swap(savedUris, sourcePosition, targetPosition)
                adapter.notifyItemMoved(sourcePosition, targetPosition)
              
               //update your list ,i am using mutable livedata
               _list.postValue(savedUris) //updating existing list with new data

              // Notifying
                if (sourcePosition < targetPosition) {
                    adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(
                        sourcePosition,
                        (targetPosition - sourcePosition) + 1
                    )
                } else {
                    adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(
                        targetPosition,
                        (sourcePosition - targetPosition) + 1
                    )
                }
                return true
            }
```

It is not right solution ,there may be side effect in wrong item animation